# The constructor Candidate(String, int[]) is undefined error

Tags: java

I have this code typed up but for some reason I'm getting an "The constructor Candidate(String, int[]) is undefined" error. Any idea why I'm getting the error?

```
public static void InsertNewPERSONbeforePERSON(ArrayList<Candidate> l, String Prev, String newName, int[] newVote) {
    int index = 0;
    for(Candidate person : l){
            if (l.get(index).getName().equals(Prev))
                    break;
    }
    l.add(index, new Candidate(newName, newVote));
}
```

Comment: Please also show the full `Candidate` class. Without, we can not tell you how to fix it. Only what is causing it.

Comment: What does your `Candidate` class look like?

Comment: Also, note that you probably were intending to increment index inside your loop (which should be a normal for loop instead of an enhanced for loop)

Answer (score 3):

You have no constructor for your `Candidate` class that accepts a String and an int array as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a `public Candidate(String, int[])` constructor in your Candidate class.

```
public class Candidate{

  // all variables here
  public Candidate(String s, int[] i){
     //do stuff inside constructor
  }

  //...

}
```